# Сооружение — сооружать, постройка — строить, здание — ?

Tags: этимология

А от какого корня произошло слово "здание"? Если в словах "постройка", "сооружение" понятно, от какого процесса это все происходит, а вот как насчет "здания"? Не родственное ли ему "создание"?

Answer (score 2):

Да, родственно.Здание - заимствовано из ст.-сл. яз. Там оно образовано от причастия зьданъ, относящееся к глаголу зьдати-создавать, строить, в свою очередь производного от зьдъ-глина.в др.русском зьдарь-горшечник, зьдатель-строитель. Когда в Библии говорится, что "Бог
съзьда Адама", это и значит "вылепил из глины.." Так что"здание", "зодчий", "созидать", "создавать". исторически родственны.

Comment: **Зид** на македонском, сербском и хорватском - **стена**; стена - потому что "стоит" или сложена из камней и "сидит". **Глина** на всех славянских - *глина* или *ил*, никак иначе! Горшечник у всех славян - гончар. Каменщик (тот, кто кладет камень или кирпич) - зидар, зедник..

Comment: "ГЛИНА
Общеславянское – glina.
Древнерусское – глина, гнила.
Старославянское – глина.
Слово, известное задолго до
возникновения письменности на Руси,
присутствует и в старославянском, и в
древнерусском языках, широко
употреблялось в древнерусском
обиходе. Индоевропейская база слова –
glei, отсюда однокоренная связь с
иноязычными словами: литовским –
glieti (замазывать), gleies (слизь),
древненемецким – klei (слизь),
английским clay (глина, тина), а также
латинским – gluten (родственное
glutinis – «клей»).
Слово очень древнее и в русский язык
вошло в своем основном значении (Э.с. Семенова)

Comment: И ещё глей -- это ил (в один комментарий не поместилось).

[ Словарь толкового "бердянского" языка][1]. (Можете почитать, забавный южный русский говор. Местами с юмором описано.)


  [1]: http://baranov.com.ua/slovar/109-gley

Answer (score 0):

*Здание,* *зодчий*, а ещё им родственно слово *гнездо* (соЗДано ГНЕтом).